# ES6 - How to access `this` element after binding `this` class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, this

How can I access `this` element after binding `this` class?

For example, without binding `this`:

```
$(".button-open").click(function(event) {
    console.log(this); // <a href="#" class="button-open">Open</a>
    this.openMe();
});
```

With binding `this`:

```
$(".button-open").click(function(event) {
   console.log(this); // Polygon {windowHeight: 965, scrollNum: 0}
   this.openMe();
}.bind(this));
```

How can I get and access `<a href="#" class="button-open">Open</a>` again after binding `this`?

Full code:

```
class Polygon {
    constructor() {
        this.windowHeight = $(window).height();
        this.scrollNum = 0;
    }

    // Simple class instance methods using short-hand method
    // declaration
    init() {
        var clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
        return clickMe();
    }

    clickMe() {
        $(".button-open").click(function(event) {
            console.log(this);
            this.openMe();
        }.bind(this));


        $(".button-close").click(function(event) {
            this.closeMe();
        }.bind(this));
    }

    openMe() {
        console.log(this.scrollNum); // 0
        this.scrollNum = 200;
        console.log(this.scrollNum); // 200
        return false;

    }

    closeMe() {
        console.log(this.scrollNum); // 200
        return false;
    }
}

export { Polygon as default}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The same issue with jQuery `animate`:

```
$(".element").animate({}, 'fast', 'swing', function(event) {
    console.log(this); // the element
}.bind(this));
```

After binding:

```
$(".element").animate({}, 'fast', 'swing', function(event) {
    console.log(this); // undefined
}.bind(this));
```

Any **global or bulletproof way** of getting the `element` again?

Comment: cant we access through event.target?

Comment: By using the jQuery selector again?

Comment: @Geeky yes for click but not for animate, please see my edit above.

Comment: @AndrewLi that is not ideal by repeating things.

Comment: Event.target.element

Comment: @teelou I understand. Hard to find a 'bulletproof' way to do this...

Comment: @Gauravjoshi that is wrong - `animate` has no `Event.target`.

Comment: This is kind of a ridiculous question.  It's like you're doing `elem = x;` and then asking how to get the previous value of `elem`.  You can't do that in Javascript. If you override the value of `this` with `.bind()`, then there's no generic way to get back to what `this` would have been without the `.bind()`.  If you want to get access to some value that would have been in `this`, then it's entirely specifi to the situation.  For example, the click handler can access `event.target`. There is no generic solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** The best option would be to store the context in a variable and don't overwrite `this`:

```
var context = this;
$('.element').on('click', function(event) {
  // context would be the this you need
  // this is the element you need
});
```

**2.** If you're only targeting a single element, you can do the reverse from above and save the element on which you're binding the handler into a variable and then use the variable inside the handler:

```
var el = $('.element');
el.on('click', function(event) {
  // use el here
}.bind(this));
```

Since you tagged the question with ES6, it might be better to bind the context with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) because using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is more verbose and also creates an additional function:

```
var el = $('.element');
el.on('click', (event) => {
  // this is the same as in the outer scope
  // use el here
});
```

**3.** Another option is to use the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property of the event object but this can also be any child within your element (the target is the element that dispatches the event, not the element on which you bounded the handler), thus it might require traversing up the DOM tree to find the element you need, which is less efficient.

```
var el = $('.element');
el.on('click', ({ target }) => {
  while (target.parentNode && !target.classList.contains('element')) {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  // here the target should be the element you need
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. ` target property` does not work in `animate`.

Comment: Saving the element before your event handler only works if the jQuery object is a singleton and only contains one DOM object. If it contains multiple elements, then you still don't know which element triggered the event.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic way to get access to what the value of `this` would have been if you didn't use `.bind()`.  Javascript doesn't have a way to unbind and get back what `this` would have been.  Instead, you have to look at each individual situation and see if there is some other way to get to the whatever `this` would have been.

For example, as several of us have said, in a click handler, you can access `event.target`.

The jQuery animate does not pass any arguments to its callback so if you override `this`, then there is no generic way to get back to the triggering element.  You'd have to go back to the selector again or have saved the value in a containing closure (folks commonly use a variable named `self` for that).

The only generic way to avoid this issue is to not use `.bind()` so the value of `this` is not replaced.  You can do something like this:

```
clickMe() {
    var self = this;
    $(".button-open").click(function(event) {
        // self is our ES6 object
        // this is the item that triggered the event
        console.log(this);
        self.openMe();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bound your handler, then you can still get the item that was clicked on through event.target within the handler.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

As an alternative you can simply do

```
const self = this;
```

or

```
const me = this;
```

before any of your declarations of event listeners and without binding any functions. Then within handlers you can both use `this` to refer to the current element and `self` or `me` to refer to the parent scope.

Comment: what about the case for `animate`?

Comment: thanks. i think that is the only solution after binding. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered, but here is the pattern which I usually use:

If there is single '.element', the below code will work

```
var el = $('.element');
el.click(function(target, event){
    // target is the original this
    // this is the scope object
}.bind(this, el[0]));
```

But if '.element' refers to multiple elements then below code will handle that

```
var clickHandler = function(target, event){
    // target is the original this
    // this is the scope object
}.bind(this);

$('.element').click(function(e) {
    return clickHandler(this, e);
});
```

Comment: btw, `target` is not the same as `event.target` - they are two different things.

Comment: yes, it is "el" (jquery object) that you passed on binding

Comment: then target is NOT the original this.

Comment: thanks for the update. good solution for binding this even tho it is a bit harder to understand/ read.